MariaDB consuming swap on AlmaLinux 9.4
After upgrading from AlmaLinux 9.3 to 9.4, MariaDB started consuming swap more and more on several servers.
Using MariaDB 10.11.8. Having vm.swappiness = 1.
MySQLTuner 2.5.3 shows:
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 9h 12m 55s (780K q [23.532 qps], 33K conn, TX: 3G, RX: 1G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 88% / 12%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 3.5G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 3.3G global + 1.7M per thread (25 max threads)
[--] Performance_schema Max memory usage: 110M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 3.4G (45.86% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 3.5G (46.12% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/780K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 52% (13/25)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00% (0/33528)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 32.2% (255K cached / 793K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1 temp sorts / 144K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 54% (34K on disk / 63K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (13 created / 33K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (460K hits / 464K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (1200) is greater than number of tables (760)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (72/19K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (3K immediate / 3K locks)
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] General MyIsam metrics:
[--]  +-- Total MyISAM Tables  : 5
[--]  +-- Total MyISAM indexes : 73.7M
[--]  +-- KB Size :80.0M
[--]  +-- KB Used Size :18.3M
[--]  +-- KB used :22.9%
[--]  +-- Read KB hit rate: 82.5% (17K cached / 3K reads)
[--]  +-- Write KB hit rate: 0% (0 cached / 0 writes)
[!!] Key buffer used: 22.9% (18.3M used / 80.0M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 80.0M/73.7M
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 82.5% (17K cached / 3K reads)
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB Buffer Pool size ( 2.7G ) under limit for 64 bits architecture: (17179869184.0G )
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.7G / 2.6G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 700.0M * 1/2.7G should be equal to 25%
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 64 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.78% (24369729 hits / 24423883 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 89.95% (628956 hits / 699243 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 70287 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/352.0K
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 93.9% (566K cached / 34K reads)
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    MyISAM engine is deprecated, consider migrating to InnoDB
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
    tmp_table_size (> 192M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 192M)
    key_buffer_size (~ 19M)
    innodb_log_buffer_size (> 64M)

Everything worked fine on AlmaLinux 9.3.

With your browser, search for AlmaLinux 9.4 changelog and you will find 9.4 is a BETA version and is NOT recommended for production servers.  Consider getting back to 9.3 and avoid installing BETA versions of anything in the future.

General Availability of AlmaLinux 9.4 Stable: https://almalinux.org/blog/2024-05-06-announcing-94-stable/

Thanks for the news on Stable release.  Additional DB information request, please.
OS, Version?
Cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide swap reducing suggestions.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide swap reducing suggestions.

Here you go: https://justpaste.it/2kxoc

Analysis in process.  Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_page_cleaners';

It returns "Empty set".

Thank you.  Suggestions for reducing swap will be posted today as an answer.

This is not an actionable alert. Instead, use it in your capacity planning.
Think, and do your own estimate. Add the configured buffer memory to the maximum number of DB processes based on total connections. Do you agree that under half the host's memory is maximum? If so, and there are no other significant workloads on this box, memory is expected to be sufficient. Three quarters of host memory utilized is the guideline I start with, adjust to your preference.
Possible issues are flagged with !!  contrast to the OK. Compare with other items tagged as "bad" either in your output or some example output in the source code.  Also the source code is a giant but self-contained mysqltuner.pl script.  You can read it to find out how any item is collected and evaluated.

I've added more metrics to the original post, but not sure what to address. Also not sure why the issue came up on several servers right after AlmaLinux upgrade.

Are other apps running on the same server?  What is the slowest query?  SlowLog -- that may lead to the biggest user of RAM and/or swap.

Nginx runs on the same server. It hosts several WordPress websites. Slow queries are logged just during the backup.

Suggestions to consider for your MariaDB my.cnf [mysqld] section.
Goal: reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty below 9,346 on last Show Global Status
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0.001  # from 0 % to enable pre-flushing
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0.002  # 90 percent to reduce MVCC mgmt resources

Goal: reconsider innodb_buffer_pool_size (ibps) and associated variables to support workload
innodb_old_blocks_pct=1  # from 37 percent of ibpsize reserved
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=10  # from 25 percent set aside from ibps for chg mgmt
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G  # from less than 3G of your 8G server.

Table access is being starved by the OS Open Files limit shown by ulimit -a report
From your OS Command Prompt,
ulimit -n 30000 and press enter to enable more open file handles than todays 1024 limit.

This is a dynamic variable for your OS and does not require OS stop/start.
To make this variable persistent, view this url for an example only.
https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/
Your specifics may vary slightly.  Make your limit 30000 not the 500000 listed in the example.
In your my.cnf [mysqld] section,
table_open_cache_instances=2  # from 8, you only have 4 cores available.
table_open_cache=2048  # from 1200 because table_open_cache and innodb_open_files should always be matched.

There are many more opportunities to make your AlmaLinux / MariaDB 10.11.8 instance perform better.

Ivan, MariaDB 10.11.8 Changelog indicates Stable release date was 16 May, 2024.  Many people would not use any release with less than 90 days of release.  You probably do not want to be on the bleeding/reporting edge of problems discovered with a new version of software.

Many thanks for your help and time Wilson!
Applied all the changes you suggested and added /etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf:
`
Enable more open file handles than default 1024 limit

soft nofile 30000
hard nofile 30000
`
Hope that's fine?

I understand your point with MariaDB 10.11.8 release date.
Will monitor the behavior and keep you posted.

Ivan, Looking forward to a post from you in a week on your perspective of applying suggestions to your instance.

It's happening again :( 18 hours after restarting, MariaDB ate up 1 GB of swap...

Please post TEXT results of reports (with date and time) you are using to observe swap space usage. And logged in as root, complete SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Also, please post complete php-fpm configuration information for analysis.

Wilson, thanks for getting back to me. Please check the latest reports: https://justpaste.it/aihch

Ivan,           I suspect there is a php-fpm.ini with much more content than the recent post a few hours ago.  If you could post the whole file, it could be helpful.  What is your perception of response time after these few config changes?

Things appear to be faster. But I'm worried that the server might crash, because it has 7 MB free out of 2559 MB swap. At the same time, 3560 MB of memory is available!? Other php-fpm files are default files php-fpm.conf and www.conf from Remi's RPM repository's php82-php-fpm package.

Consider raising your swap space to 6GB - a Red Hat suggested minimum for any server. Please email whatever files you are using as attachments to mydatalinks@mysqlservertuning.com for analysis.

That didn't solve the issue. After 4 days, swap is using 3.8G out of 8G.

What was the last date the server crashed?

Please email whatever files you are using to manage php-fpm and your www.conf as attachments to mydatalinks@mysqlservertuning.com for analysis.  Modify any variables with **** that you do not want visible. Please.

Server didn't crash ever. I was worried that it might happen due to uncontrolled swap usage. Just sent the configuration files to your email address.
